# How do you keep a personal wiki (TiddlyWiki) current and in sync in multiple locations?

Tags: project-management, development-environment, wiki, tiddlywiki

If one were to use TiddlyWiki as a personal database for notes and code snippets, how would you go about keeping it in sync between multiple machines. Would a svn/cvs etc work. How would you handle merges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These options are all good, but I would just put it on a USB key.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this is the easiest option you found.

Comment: Are you being serious?  Putting a portable wiki on a usb key is an extremely straightforward and foolproof way to access it from multiple machines; I actually can't think of any way that is easier.

Comment: Well, I guess if you have it *only* on the USB drive, you won't have problems with synchronization.  Bummer if you forget the drive at work or at home, though, because now all your information isn't accessible.  Using Windows Live Sync would let you have it on both computers and keep it up to date without having to carry around a USB drive.

Comment: It's been a while since this question, and I think the tides have shifted technology-wise -- I personally would use DropBox or something like it now for this purpose.  If the original asker is still around, it might be a good idea to change the "accepted" answer to a more modern solution.

Comment: <Snark>Hmmm... Can't find the USB port on my iPad.</Snark>

Comment: @GuyStarbuck, **And then your USB drops and crack. What next?**

Comment: it's been 8 years since I answered this question - the cloud hadn't been invented yet. See below on using "up and comer DropBox" :)

Answer (score 30):

One option is the up-and-comer [DropBox](http://getdropbox.com). A free filesharing service that gives you 2GB free, and no limit to the number of computers you share on.

Define a shared folder, put your tiddlywiki files in there, and then point the local editing to the shared drive. Any changes are automatically reflected.

Note: I have no connections to DropBox other than the fact that I've been reading lots about it, and am trialing it for my personal use.

Comment: DropBox is a perfect solution for this sort of thing.  (Note: I don't have a connection to DropBox either, but I think its a fantastic service, I use it multiple times a day, and its already saved my bacon more than once.)

Comment: I use dropbox for this myself, the main benefit is instant version control (no need to do it myself with commits and such)

Comment: Used DropBox for a while but found TiddlySpot solution very simple and effective. You could combine the 2 approaches as I did for a time.

Comment: Maybe SpiderOak if you are paranoid and want encryption.

Comment: I am using btsync https://www.getsync.com/ to sync tiddlywiki.

Answer (score 10):

Use [TiddlySpot](http://www.tiddlyspot.com), its online all the time and private

Comment: I find it incredible that this site is really still online in 2020.

Comment: Kyrylo, it looks like you spoke a few months too soon.

Answer (score 7):

Tiddlywiki is well suited for version control (since it is a single text file).

Just put it on a personal SVN or Git repository accessible from the web, and you can keep it in sync with many places (office, home, laptop, etc.).

I use this method, and it works pretty well. You can even have several versions of your notes and resolve conflicts using diff tools. And obviously with revision control, you can work "offline" and sync later.

Comment: How easy is it to resolve conflicts between two different versions of a TiddlyWiki HTML file?

Answer (score 5):

I just created a new Tiddlywiki at [TiddlySpot](http://tiddlyspot.com/). It allows you to keep a local copy of the Tiddlywiki and also sync it up with the server.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your own web server (and don't want to use TiddlySpot), try [this code](http://tiddlywiki.bidix.info/#HowToUpload) to enable saving to your own server.

Answer (score 2):

I have a [MonkeyGTD](http://monkeygtd.tiddlyspot.com/) wiki that is on http://TiddlySpot.com. I have a local copy of it on my work PC and do my work during the day on it, and periodically upload to TiddlSpot during the day and at the end of the day. If I need to access it or update it after work I will make changes to the online version and then the next morning I do an **Import** back into my local file.

It's true that if I forget to do an update or do them in the wrong order I will lose information, but it's "good enough".

There is probably a way to use the **Sync** functionality to prevent this, but I haven't researched this option yet.

Comment: TiddlySpot has a "Save to Web" option. You can make edits from any online computer. Order of sync is important. There are at least 7-8 versions on the site so doing a rollback to an older version is quite easy. Refer the [TiddlySpot FAQ](http://faq.tiddlyspot.com)

Answer (score 2):

If you might want to edit your wiki on several computers at the same time, you would definitely want a server-based solution that syncs at a finer level than the file. Giewiki (http://giewiki.appspot.com) is a server-based TiddlyWiki solution based on Google's App Engine, which does just that. And unlike any other hosted TiddlyWikis that I know of, you can create several pages in any hierachy and navigate them through an auto-generated sitemap. You can try it out by creating a subdomain site at giewiki.appspot.com, or you can download the source and install it into a free appspot site of your own. And you can make it as personal or public as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Try [FolderShare](https://foldershare.com/).

Comment: Mesh might be a better choice.  I think FS is going bye bye when Mesh gets out of beta.

Answer (score 1):

I store my TiddlyWiki files on a USB flash drive that I keep with me no matter what computer I might be using. No need to bother synchronizing across other computers. It gets backed up regularly when I back up the flash drive itself on my primary workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option: Use a different [personal wiki](http://luminotes.com) called Luminotes, which you can either access online from different computers or download and run on your own computer (yes, even a USB drive). Luminotes has definitely got some similarities to TiddlyWiki, but in many ways it's simpler to learn and use.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned SVN, but if you don't mind using git, Github's [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) is a great solution. Edit locally or from the github remote repo.

Answer (score -8):

Why not just setup something like DokuWiki on a webserver?  You do have your own web server, right?  You can get a virtual hosted solution for $19/mo these days.